# Using bootstrap file input to upload a file through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file

I am developing a website. My goal is to have the possibility to upload a file to the website and put it in a Blob like that I can use it in my javascript code.

My problem is during the upload part: I use bootstrap file input by Krajee to upload the file. Here is my html part where I have the input tag to upload a file:

```
 <label class="control-label">Select File</label>
 <form id="form_file" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
 <input id="file-sign" type="file" class="file" data-show-preview="false">
 </form>
```

And here is my javascript code:

```
var file = $("#file-sign");

file.fileinput({
    uploadUrl: 'fileUpload.php', // using Ajax
    showCaption: true,
    showUpload: true,
    uploadLabel: "Submit",
    uploadClass: "btn btn-success",
    showRemove: false,
    uploadAsync: true,
    //maxFileSize: 4096,
    maxFilesNum: 1,
    maxFileCount: 1,
    multiple: false,
    showPreview: true
});

file.on('fileuploaded', function(event, data, previewId, index) {
    console.log('File uploaded triggered');
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.response.data);
});

file.on('fileloaded', function(event, file, previewId, index, reader) {
    console.log("fileloaded");
});
```

What I don't understand is how to get back the file in my javascript code.
I read on the webpage of krajee that when I put the uploadUrl field, it will be an AJAX upload and I need to put the name of the file which will take in account the AJAX account. So I created a PHP file (I don't know anything in PHP. I write this file in searching on internet). Here it is:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/plain");

$nick = (isset($_FILES['file_data'])) ? $_FILES['file_data'] : NULL;

if ($nick) {
    echo $nick;
} else {
    echo "FAIL";
}

?>
```

And I think it is not correct because in my web console I have: 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/.../fileUpload.php. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

I guess my message is a bit confusing, but to clear my problem is I don't know how to retrieve my file in the line of my javascript code:

```
file.on('fileuploaded'.......
```

I hope somebody can help me :)

Comment: It seems like you're not running this through a web server. Is that true?

Comment: @PatrickQ it's right. I am running this locally.

Comment: You can run it locally and still have it run through a server (such as apache). However, that bit about `file:///` is what made me think that you're not. You're going to need a server and PHP running to be able to process PHP files (and make ajax requests like the one you're trying to make).

Comment: @PatrickQ but there is a way without using PHP and a server to upload a file to the website and retrieve in javascript code? I don't to store it, I just need to sign it.

Comment: What do you mean by "sign it"? What exactly is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I will use some cryptographic tools to sign or verify the file through nodes but I don't think it is important concerning my problem.

Comment: Looks like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) might be more along the lines of what you're looking for than the jQuery plugin that you're using now.

Comment: Thank you for your precious advice! That works :)